# flash as3 Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

```
Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at sto()[C:\Users\dani\Desktop\folder (2)\sto.as:11]
at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
at runtime::AppRunner/run()
at ADLAppEntry/run()
at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

I create a button with flash as3. Can you guys help me

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class sto extends MovieClip {


    public function sto() {

     start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,kdown);//start is the instance name of a movieclip

            }
               function kdown(event:MouseEvent):void{
        nextFrame();
       }

}
```

}

I think the problem is  start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,kdown);
but I don't know what to do

Comment: what is start ?  where is declared?

Comment: `start` doesn't exist, most likely.

Comment: Not enough information.   What is the context of this `sto` class? is it the class file for a FlashPro movieClip library object, and does that object have a child on the timeline called `start`?  At any rate, it probably wouldn't be available in the constructor. You'll want to listen for the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event before trying to access a timeline instance

Answer (score 0):

The error messages really have meaning plus clues as to where the error is occurring.

```
Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at sto()[C:\Users\dani\Desktop\folder (2)\sto.as:11]
```

So... something being referenced is `null`
and the error is occurring on line 11 in the file "sto.as"

As several commenters have pointed out, that line is likely

```
start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,kdown);
```

So `start` is either undefined or not initialized. So what is `start`? Where is it declared and initialized?

Mmm.... ok. It looks like you are just trying to add an event listener to the instance.

Use:

```
  this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,kdown);
```

Comment: start is the instance name of a movieclip